# create_or_update method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
if ClassName.exists?(["id = ?", self.id])
  object = ClassName.find_by_name(self.name)
  object.update_attributes!( :street_address => self.street_address,
    :city_name => self.city_name,
    :name => self.org_unit_name,
    :state_prov_id => self.state_prov_id,
    :zip_code => self.zip_code)
else
  ClassName.create! :street_address => self.street_address,
    :city_name => self.city_name,
    :federalid => self.federalid,
    :name => self.org_unit_name,
    :state_prov_id => self.state_prov_id,
    :zip_code => self.zip_code
end
```

I have code like this. I would like to improve it so that it uses a method, something like create_or_update.

```
    ClassName.create_or_update_by_name(:name => self.name,
    :street_address => self.street_address,
    :city_name => self.city_name,
    :federalid => self.federalid,
    :name => self.org_unit_name,
    :state_prov_id => self.state_prov_id,
    :zip_code => self.zip_code)
```

If the `name` exists in the database then it should update that object otherwise it should create a new object.

Is there is any method that exists that I can do this with?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
my_class = ClassName.find_or_initialize_by_name(name)

my_class.update_attributes(
   :street_address => self.street_address,
   :city_name => self.city_name,
   :federalid => self.federalid,
   :state_prov_id => self.state_prov_id,
   :zip_code => self.zip_code
)
```

As of **Rails 6**, `update_attributes!` and `update_attributes` [is deprecated](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/8705) for `update!` and `update`, respectively:

```
my_class.update(
   :street_address => self.street_address,
   :city_name => self.city_name,
   :federalid => self.federalid,
   :state_prov_id => self.state_prov_id,
   :zip_code => self.zip_code
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. As a note, the name doesn't have to be passed in again since it was already initialized with a name. Also the hash brackets aren't needed here.

Comment: And so operations are separate, not in a transaction.

Comment: find_or_intialize_by_method is deprecated as of Rails 4

Answer (score 10):

The checked answer above works well for Rails 3. That said the `find_or_initialize_by_attribute` methods were deprecated in Rails 4. This is the new way. See [Rails4 Deprecation warning for find_or_initialize_by method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472584/rails4-deprecation-warning-for-find-or-initialize-by-method)

```
person = Person.find_or_initialize(name: 'name')   
person.update_attributes(other_attrs)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
person = Person.find_by_name(name) || Person.new(:name => name)
person.update_attributes!(:street_address => street_address, :city_name => city_name) #etc etc
```