# Ruby Rails - save vs update where method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to make a inventory system, my table has the index "id" by default as primary key. My inventory number should be unique value to create new entry in the table, if the inventory already exists then it shall update the attributes. How do do this? By making inventory number as primary key? or is there any way to check and update an inventory already exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked: [create_or_update method in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024010/create-or-update-method-in-rails)

```
my_class = ClassName.find_or_initialize_by_name(name)

my_class.update_attributes({:street_address => self.street_address,.....})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have unique field `number` (for example). Than you can use `find_or_create_by_<field_name>` dirty method.

```
@ticket = Ticket.find_or_create_by_number(503)
```

**Updated:**

```
@ticket.attrib = 'new attribute value'
@ticket.save
```

or

```
@ticket.update_attribute :attrib, 'new attribute value'
```

Comment: Thanks ck3g! Does this method update the existing record too?

Comment: if Ticket already exists this method just grab it. And create if not exists. After it you can use update_attribute, save etc.