# First_or_create with update on match?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I really like the `first_or_create` method:

```
# Find the first user named Scarlett or create a new one with a particular last name.
User.where(:first_name => 'Scarlett').first_or_create(:last_name => 'Johansson')
# => <User id: 2, first_name: 'Scarlett', last_name: 'Johansson'>
```

I was wondering how I could also have this update the User with the last_name 'Johannson' if it's not present or different.  Looking for the briefest way of doing this.  A one liner similar to the above would be ideal.

One possible approach is [using first_or_initialize combined with update_attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3024871/378622).  The only concern I have with this approach is that it would run an update even if there were a 100% match on the fields provided.

Answer (score 23):

Zaid is VERY close to correct.

```
User.where(first_name: 'Scarlett').first_or_create.update(last_name: 'Johansson')
```

Detailed differences here. (Note: this is for Rails 3+ and Rails 4+)

1. The difference between `first_or_create` vs. `first_or_initialize` is that `_initialize` uses the `.new` method and does not save the record vs `.create` and auto saves it.
2. The difference between `.update` vs. `.update_attributes`, `.update_attributes` is what you use when you have a hash of values, typically coming from a form submit like `params`. On the other hand,`.update`  lets you easily specify each attribute as shown above `(field_column: value, field_column2: value2)`, etc.

And just like Zaid said, but it applies to both `.update` and `.update_attributes`, rails database updates "...only hits the database if there are changes to be made..."

Comment: update is a private method. Calling it in this context gives "NoMethodError: private method `update' called..." You need to use update_attributes if you want to do it all in one line.

Comment: I'm not sure how you coded this, but you shouldn't have any problems either way.

I am currently using this in a view and controller in this format:
` Session.where(user_id: @user, legal_case_id: @case).first_or_create.update(last_active: now)`

Update has always been a public method. (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update).

Even if you are using .update_attributes, it's an alias to .update after Rails 3+ (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attributes). So it "almost" should not matter either way.

Comment: `update_attributes` will be remove in Rails 6.1: `DEPRECATION WARNING: update_attributes is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 6.1 (please, use update instead)`

Answer (score 6):

`first_or_initialize` with `update_attributes` should be fine. Rails is smart enough that `update_attributes` only hits the database if there are changes to be made (which you should be able to confirm for yourself using the console/logs).

Comment: `update_attributes` will be remove in Rails 6.1: `DEPRECATION WARNING: update_attributes is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 6.1 (please, use update instead)`