# Updating rails database records with CSV import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, csv

I have the following controller method:

```
class InventoryItemsController < ApplicationController

    def import
        params.permit(:code, :vendor_id, :price)
        InventoryItem.import(params[:file])
        redirect_to admin_index_path, notice: "Inventory Imported."
    end
end
```

This then calls my model method:

```
class InventoryItem < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        InventoryItem.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
end
```

What I want to now be able to do is use a similar CSV import method to update existing records (for price changes etc.), only adding new records if the `:code` attribute is unique. I could probably do this if it were a simple update for one record, but I'm not sure how to tackle this with a CSV upload. Help please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer might help you out: [create_or_update method in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024010/create-or-update-method-in-rails)

Try using something like the below with `find_or_initialize_by_code`.  Your code would look something like

```
def self.import(file)
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    my_object = InventoryItem.find_or_initialize_by_code(code)
    my_object.update_attributes(row.to_hash)
end
```

Comment: So `update_attributes` will create a new record if the resource doesn't exist?

Comment: Not exactly.  find_or_initialize_by will create it (initialize it) if it doesn't already exist.  See http://rubyquicktips.com/post/344181578/find-or-create-an-object-in-one-command for some more info.  From this site, "The find_or_create_by_ dynamic finder will return the object if it already exists and otherwise creates it, then returns it."  EDIT: I mentioned the find_or_create_by, the article also talks about find_or_initialize_by.  It depends on whether you want to save the object or not after this method.