# Adding or updating record with user id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

Ruby on Rails 3, I have an edit page with two select_tag submissions. One has users that have the attribute :attend = "Yes" and the other has users that have the attribute :attend = "No" or nil. I am trying to get the select_tag submissions to create or update the Certificate table for the user. As of now I know it is POSTing the user id and name. I do not know how to get the controller or model to take the user id and create or update with the :attend attribute value of "Yes" or "No". The app will create a new record with the correct user id but not with :attend since it is not in my select_tag submission.

Here is my edit:

```
<%= form_for @untrained do |f| %>
            <p> Trained Users </p>
            <%= select_tag "certificate[user_id]", options_for_select(@current_trained.collect{|x| [x.name, x.id]}), {:multiple => :multiple} %>
            <%= f.submit "Un-Train", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
        <%= form_for @trained do |f| %>
            <p> Non-Trained Users </p>
            <%= select_tag "certificate[user_id]", options_for_select(@non_trained.collect{|x| [x.name, x.id]}), {:multiple => :multiple} %>
            <%= f.submit "Trained", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
```

Here is my controller:

```
@trained = Certificate.new(params[:certificate])
@untrained = Certificate.update(params[:user_id])
```

Here is my model:

```
attr_accessible :attend, :pass, :user_id
belongs_to :user
validates :user_id, presence: true
```

How do you set the controller to create or update a new record with :attend as "Yes"?
How do you update the record with :attend as "No"?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have u tried in the controller after

```
if @trained.save
```

put

```
@trained.update_attributes(attend: "yes")
```

or no depending on the type u want.

Also have a look at this for the create/update method in rails.

[create_or_update method in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024010/create-or-update-method-in-rails)

Comment: Can you please show how do u check? If you see it in the page Rails is pulling it from the DB.In your controller you would have @trained = Certificate.new(params[:certificate]) @trained.update_attributes(attend: "yes")

Comment: My log shows the POST saving to the DB. The update attributes is not logged. When I run Certificate.all the records show nil. My views use several instance variables in loops. I even have an if statement checking for the "Yes" Certificate.find_by_user_id(@trained_user_id).attend == "Yes" and it shows them in my view ???

Comment: try adding this to your form <%= f.hidden_field :attend, :value => "Yes" %> and then check the params and update the column with that one.

Comment: Im not sure where I would add the hidden_field since this is a select_tag. Also, I discovered that my view is not caring if the attend is nil or not. It is only showing if the user has a record with its user id. So the attend attribute was not saved.

Comment: What is the log when the update_attribute is called. If you are on a development env you should see the update sql query being executed.

Comment: The update_attribute is never run. After the initial POST is commited is redirects back edit page. That was it. I had to place the update_attributes before the redirect. Sorry for such a stupid mistake :/