# Create or update records in seeds.db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

In my production DB, I don't want to drop all of the info, but I do want to update some fields for existing rows using my seeds.db file (I added a new column).

What is the right way to go about this? Should I be creating a seperate rake task or something? Should I have `if exists, update` logic in my seeds.db file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something similar to this question - [create_or_update method in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024010/create-or-update-method-in-rails)

Then write your seeds.rb to use update_or_create rather than just creating records. This way you can simply re-run your seed data to refresh your DB?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to manage this situation.

If you just want some columns of your database to be copied then either the seeds file or the rake task is enough.

Moreover,

Model.find_or_create_by_field("XXXXX") will do the trick.

If you want the whole database to be copied to production I would go with taps gem (watch this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql) or if you are deploying to heroku just as simple as heroku pg:pull